# php socket programming issue: Connection reset by peer

Tags: java, php, sockets, websocket

I have an php application, which connects to a java application using sockets. In java application we have timeout set for 10 seconds.

I have a huge amount of data which needs to be processed in the middle of the application. Due to which when i try to use the socket after processing I receive the socket error of connection reset by peer.

Now when I try to shutdown(socket_shutdown) the connection and re open the connection, am receiving an error Transport endpoint is not connected on socket_send,socket_receive. Would appreciate any guidance on this issue.

NOTE : am trying to use singleton method for socket connections.

Comment: Can you supply some code in which you connect to your server from PHP? Guess is, when your client does 'socket_shutdown', you try to send a 'thx and goodbye' to java serverside, which is not possible since connection is already lost/denied from serverside

Comment: A common cause of `connection reset by peer` is closing the socket without reading what the client has sent. But without seeing your code it's impossible to say what the issue might be.

Comment: How about keeping the socket alive while you proces the data?

Answer (score 0):

I am using in my PHP application massively socket connections [10 different PHP Apache threads per second to my own self written C++ Server].

This is the code which I use in PHP and it works:

```
$sIP = gethostbyname('MyDomain');

# create the socket
$iSocket = socket_create( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP );
if ($iSocket === FALSE )
{
    writeLogFile(sprintf("socket_create() failed: %s",
                    socket_strerror(socket_last_error())));
    exit;
}

# load some default values from the app table
$iTimeOut = 180
$iPort = 11211;

socket_set_option($iSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array("sec" => $iTimeOut, "usec" => 0));
$iResult = socket_connect($iSocket, $sIP, $iPort);

if ( $iResult === FALSE )
{
    $sError = sprintf("<br>socket_connect(%d) failed with code %d: %s",
                    $iSocket, $iResult, socket_strerror(socket_last_error($iSocket)));
    writeLogFile($sError);
    die($sError);
    exit;
}

# $sHttpParameter has the value which has to be sent over the socket
socket_write($iSocket, $sHttpParameter, strlen($sHttpParameter));
# for my purpose the answer is just an OK/FAILED
$sAnswer = socket_read($iSocket, 1000);     
socket_close($iSocket);
```

Are you sure the problem is not the JAVA application?